# Maven build is successful although npm deployment has an error

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I try to deploy a `npm module` via `exec-maven-plugin`. I use the `nexus-npm` tool from https://github.com/arkanjoms/nexus-npm.

In my pom I execute it like this:

```
<execution>
  <id>Deploy module via nexus-npm</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>exec</goal>
  </goals>
  <phase>deploy</phase>
  <configuration>
    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/npm</workingDirectory>
    <executable>nexus-npm</executable>
    <arguments>
      <argument>deploy</argument>
    </arguments>
    <environmentVariables>
      <HOME>${project.build.directory}/npm</HOME>
    </environmentVariables>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

Everything works fine, but when the deployment is failing the maven build is still marked as successful. How can I tell maven that the build should fail when the deployment is not successful?

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 400
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! Repository is read only: npm-internal-snapshots : mypackage

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Apps\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-12T11_02_39_129Z-debug.log
[default.js-info]: Rollback files.
[default.js-info]: Cleaning files.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:12 min (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-12T13:02:39+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/396M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To clearify I know why the deployment is failing, that is not my question. I only want to know how to mark the maven build as failure when the deployment has an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [arkanjoms/nexus-npm](https://github.com/arkanjoms/nexus-npm) plugin uses [`app/publish-snapshot.js`](https://github.com/arkanjoms/nexus-npm/blob/b28f1db17506ae0846936c2b9df71d685b4142c0/app/publish-snapshot.js#L9)

```js
publishSnapshot: function (snapshotRepository) {
    log.info('publish snapshot => ' + snapshotRepository);
    shell.exec('npm publish --registry=' + snapshotRepository);
},
```

That means the [`shelljs/shelljs`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) `exec` command does not check its return code.

It should be:

```js
if (shell.exec('npm publish --registry=' + snapshotRepository).code !== 0) {
  shell.echo('Error: npm publish snapshot failed');
  shell.exit(1);
}
```

Similarly, the call of that publish snapshot step don't expect any error in [`app/commands.js`](https://github.com/arkanjoms/nexus-npm/blob/b28f1db17506ae0846936c2b9df71d685b4142c0/app/commands.js#L64-L77)

```js
    deploy: function () {
        this.verify();
        this.backup();
        if (commander.release) {
            tag.createTag(this.appConfig, this.config.tag, this.message);
            release.publishRelease(this.appConfig.packageJson.distributionManagement.releaseRegistry);
            release.updatePkgVersion(this.appConfig, this.message);
            rollback.clean();
        } else {
            snapshot.addDateToVersion(this.appConfig);
            snapshot.publishSnapshot(this.appConfig.packageJson.distributionManagement.snapshotRegistry);
            rollback.rollback();
        }
    },
```

As the current plugin implementation stands, it won't be easy to mark the maven build as failure when the deployment has an error.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly the problem. I forked the project and tried this and it works like a charm

Comment: @ochs.tobi Well done! That could be a PR (pull request) to be done to the original project!